# Jmeter Test Stalls When RMI TCP Connection Opens?

Tags: tcp, jmeter, performance-testing, rmi

I've been seeing inconsistent JMeter runs, and they seem to correlate when I see an RMI TCP Connection thread open?

CPU seems to stall for a moment at 0%, and the corresponding affect on heap (see photos).

This is a test just run on the machine i.e. no distribution.

Any ideas why this might be? It causes inconsistencies in my test run which sees requests fall off..

[image]

[image]

Comment: RMI does a bit ofmucking around in the accepting thread, which it really shouldn't, such as getting the client hostname. This should all happen in the connection thread. This would stall subsequent connect requests.

Comment: Do you think this connection is as a result of using Visual VM as opposed to the actual application itself?